# Finding dynamically generated components Unity

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, find, components

I have a game object and I'm generating a component for that object by

```
var arcGISMapViewComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<ArcGISMapViewComponent>();
```

under the Void Start()

However, I have another class that is

```
public void ReadStringInput(string s)
```

I also need to show there the existence of arcGISMapViewComponent but since it's not generated yet in the beginning I'm getting an error which is

'arcGISMapViewComponent' could not be found how can I solve this?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is orbetter **was** a custom JavaScript flavour-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: As a thumbrule of mine: Do whatever you can without relying on other components in `Awake`. The rest initialize in `Start`. Beyond that you always have to either play with execution order or use events

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Awake() {}` to make sure some code (component creation in your case) is called before other `Start` code. If your different class is not a `MonoBehaviour` then you should create an event and `Invoke` it notifying that component was created and from your different class subscribe on that event.